# Android: Keep asynctask even after app is killed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code below that I'm using to test the life cycle of the asynctask. What I want to do is to let the asynctask finish even if the app is forcibly closed by the user. It shows a notification which increments the progress every second. The asynctask is called from a Fragment. However, when I forcibly terminate the app by pressing all apps then swiping it off, the notification stops and no longer increments. See my code below.

Is this the case or am I doing something wrong?

Also, the reason I'm using asynctask is because I want to allow the user to cancel the task whenever possible. I believe this can't be done with IntentService? (Correct me if I'm wrong on this).

Appreciate any help.

UPDATE: I am now trying foreground service as suggested by @John Wick and @Abishek. However, I am not able to stop the service the way I want it to. When I click stop, the loop goes on and does not stop.

public class ForegroundService extends Service {

```
    boolean isCancelled = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("Start")) {
            Log.d("Action", "Start");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction("Start");
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            closeIntent.setAction("Stop");
            PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            NotificationManagerCompat manager = (NotificationManagerCompat.from(this));
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            builder.setContentTitle("Truiton Music Player");
            builder.setTicker("Truiton Music Player");
            builder.setContentText("My Music");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            builder.setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false));
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Stop", pCloseIntent);

            startForeground(1, builder.build());
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Log.d("Service", String.valueOf(i));
                builder.setProgress(9, i, false);

                if (isCancelled) {
                    builder.setContentTitle("Cancelled");
                    builder.setContentText("");
                    builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                    builder.mActions.clear();
                    manager.notify(1, builder.build());
                } else {
                    if (i == 9) {
                        builder.setContentTitle("Done");
                        builder.setContentText("");
                        builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                        manager.notify(1, builder.build());
                    } else {
                        manager.notify(1, builder.build());
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            stopForeground(true);
        } else {
            Log.d("Action", "Start");
            isCancelled = true;
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }


}
```

Comment: you need to implement a background service for this and make that service available even your app is close

Comment: You'll need a Service (not an Intent Service) if you want work to complete independently of your apps lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Foreground Service to make it work even if app is closed. See this link for a demo implementation.

http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/

Comment: I am now trying to use Foreground service. However, I am not able to stop it the way I want it to. Please see updated code above.

Comment: use startForeground(1, builder.build()); just above the loop and stopForeground(true) below the loop.

Comment: updated my code as suggested but click Stop does nothing still.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is Service and yes it can be stopped when you no longer need it, the advantage over AysncTask is even when you terminate your app from task manager you service whon't get affected.

To stop a service you will need to call

stopService(new Intent(//Service));

Now if you want to show notification which updates a counter then use foreground service for this.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Answer (score 0):

You can Keep `asynctask` even after app is killed but when your `doInBackground` work finished and `onPostExecute` method work on that time you need to require available object of `context` otherwise app will crashed.